# Como cambio los valores de una columna basado en los valores de otra columna en Pandas?

Tags: pandas

Tengo un dataset de 250K registros que tiene estas columns y debo cambiar la columna "Value" a lo siguiente:
Si la cuenta es "50000" o "60000" mantener el valor
Si la cuenta empieza con "6" dividirla entre 1000
Si la cuenta empieza con 7, 8 9 o una Letra, dividirla entre -1000

Account Value
50000    65
50000    98
60000    82
60000    71
60100    945,345
60200    856,395
70100    715,234
70200    523,712

El dataset resultante deberia de quedar asi:
Account Value
50000    65

50000    98,
60000    82,
60000    71,
60100    945,345,
60200    856,395
70100    (715,234)
70200    (523,712)

he probado varias cosas que encontre, una de las ultimas es:

```
Non6 = step01["Account"]!="60000"
Non5 = step01["Account"]!="50000"

xFact = [Non6 & Non5]
step01["Value2"] = 0
step01["Value2"] = step01["Value"] step01.loc[xFact["Value"]]= [xFact["Value"]]/1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Una de las operaciones que puedes usar para resolver tu problema es `map`. Con ella seleccionas una columna y le aplicas la función que quieras.

Esta es una función siguiendo las reglas que has descrito, tú puedes cambiarla cuaando quieras.

```
def rules_to_change(x):
    #Aislamos el número por el que comienza
    x_string_first = int(str(x)[0])
    
    #Ponemos las condiciones
    if x == 50000 or x == 60000:
        return x
    elif x_string_first == 6:
        return x / 1000
    elif x_string_first >=7 or x_string_first <=9 or x_string_first.isalpha():
        return x / -1000

#Del DataFrame que tenemos, seleccionamos la columna que queremos mapear
df_values['Value2'].map(rules_to_change)
```